# SurveyMonkey - Restrict api survey access

Tags: surveymonkey

Is it possible to restrict the surveys available to someone with api access to only a single survey? (Without using some kind of middleware server that restricts the access externally to surveymonkey).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible - having an OAuth token to someone's account is equivalent to having the password to their account.  There are currently no limited views or restricted scopes possible with SurveyMonkey's API.